# Cloudwatch custom metrics with backdated timestamps slow to appear

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to fire custom cloudwatch metrics. Setting the timestamp on the metric events is important for us.

When I set the timestamp to a time within the past day or so, I can see the event appear practically right away on the cloudwatch control panel or using aws-cli.

The problem is when I set the timestamp to a time more than a day ago. It seems to be taking a long time before I can see the event. I haven't got exact measurements, but some events are taking around 24 hours to appear.

Is this normal? Is there any documentation that explains this anywhere? By the way I'm aware that cloudwatch only keeps events for 14 days - I'm not trying to set a timestamp that far in the past.

By the way, I'm using the Java SDK via Apache Camel to send data to cloudwatch but I don't think that's relevant - the events *are* going to cloudwatch with the appropriate timestamps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Documented behavior:

> Data that is timestamped 24 hours or more in the past may take in excess of 48 hours to become available from submission time using `GetMetricStatistics`.
>
> — http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricData.html

Comment: Great thanks - I missed that in the docs. Behaviour like this is OK so long as I know that its meant to happen.